# Theorem 9.28 Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations, inverse-function

[image]

[image]

$A(h,k)$ = $A_xh$ + $A_yk$.

Where $A_xh$ $\in$ $L(R^n)$, $A_yk$ $\in$ $L(R^m,R^n)$.

I don't understand that how does it comes from $f(a,b)$ = 0, that $f(a+h,b+k)$ = $A(h,k) + r(h,k)$ Hence I Couldn't understand the last equation on the photo .

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That is simply because
$$
f(a+h,b+k)=f(a,b)+A(h,k)+r(h,k)
$$
which follows from the definition of $A$ and $f'(a,b)$.

Comment: How does it follow from the definition of A and $f'(a,b)$ ? I guess  $A(h,k)$ = $f'(h,k)$ but then couldn't  understand from where does it come

Comment: @SerIsaac: $A=f'(a,b)$ is in the line 3 of your excerpt and $A(h,k)=f'(a,b)(h,k)$. And the definition of $f'(a,b)$ says $f(a+h,b+k)=f(a,b)+f'(a,b)(h,k)+r(h,k)$.